# How to create regex pattern that removes elements equal to a substring, if and only if it finds an enumeration inside the input string?

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm having some trouble creating a regex that if it receives a *string* with an enum ( `element, element, element, element_diferent, ... and element`) then just leave the enum element other than `hyjk11l`

**Example 1:**

Input string:

```py
"I come with hyjk11l, Mary Johnson, hyjk11l, hyjk11l, hyjk11l and hyjk11l to the center, maybe we'll buy something there"
```

the output that i need:

```py
"I come with Mary Johnson to the center, maybe we'll buy something there"
```

**Example 2:**

Input string:

```py
"In afternoon, I show hyjk11l, John, hyjk11l, and hyjk11l in the lab"
```

the output that i need:

```py
"In afternoon, I show with John in the lab"
```

**Example 3:**

Input string:

```py
"I meet with Katy Perry and hyjk11l here"
```

the output that i need:

```py
"I meet with Katy Perry here"
```

I have tried using the `replace()` function, and some regex combinations but I don't get the desired result. I think maybe I could remove with `replace()` and all the `", hyjk11l"`, `"hyjk11l"`, `", and hyjk11l"` and/or `"and hyjk11l"`, but I think that's complicated because I don't know how many times I have to do it (this seeks to be general, that is, you do not know what input string will be passed to you, for that the regex would be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```py
inputs = ["I come with hyjk11l, Mary Johnson, hyjk11l, hyjk11l, hyjk11l and hyjk11l to the center, maybe we'll buy something there",
          "In afternoon, I show hyjk11l, John, hyjk11l, and hyjk11l in the lab",
          "I meet with Katy Perry and hyjk11l here",
          "I meet him and hyjk11l and her there"
         ]

pat = r"((?:[\s+\,]|\s?and)\s?hyjk11l(?:[\s\,]?)(?=\s))"
for inp in inputs:
    tmp = re.sub(pat, "", inp)
    print(tmp)
```

Output:

```
I come with Mary Johnson to the center, maybe we'll buy something there
In afternoon, I show John in the lab
I meet with Katy Perry here
I meet him and her there
```

Check the regex at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3ky33j/1).

Explanation pattern:

- `(?:[\s+\,]|\s?and)` : non-capturing group, match one or more whitespaces or comma OR 0 or 1 whitespace and `and`
- `\s?` : 0 or 1 whitespace
- `hyjk11l` : match this word
- `(?:[\s\,]?)` : non-capturing group, match 0 or 1 whitespace or comma
- `(?=\s)` : match followed by a whitespace
- whole pattern builds one group, which will be replaced with `""`

Comment: Really thanks, It works almost perfectly but I have detected a problem in this type of sentence where the input is `"I meet with hyjk11l and Katy Perry here"` and the output is `"I meet with and Katy Perry here"` and not `"I meet with Katy Perry here"`. That  `"and"` should not be there.

Comment: thought I checked all possible enumerations. thanks for pointing that out. I will have another look.

Comment: Hmm I was thinking about how to do it, since with a simple replace() it would not be indicated since it would be removing other possible substrings "and" before and/or after

Comment: hm I'm a bit stuck. If I implement the same logic for `and` after hyjk11l, it fixes your just mentioned case, but it will also change `"I meet him and hyjk11l and her there"` to `"I meet him her there"`

Comment: I think the that for the  `"hyjk11l and"` or `"hyjk11l, and"` before using your regular expression I could use a `.replace( ,"")` function for these 2 cases, but I think it would hurt the effectiveness of the regular expression

Answer (score 0):

```
from ordered_set import OrderedSet

for s in inputs:
    # remove hyjk11l and a possible comma after
    s = re.sub(r'\b\w+\d+.*?\b,?', '', s)
    # remove repeated words (the second **and** is removed)
    s = ' '.join(OrderedSet(s.split()))
    print(s)

OUTPUT
I come with Mary Johnson, and to the center, maybe we'll buy something there
In afternoon, I show John, and in the lab
I meet with Katy Perry and here
I meet him and her there
```